# Load rake tasks from ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm writing a gem and I want to have an access to the gem rake tasks from my rails app. To do this I use Railties.

I have `lib/frontrockets-rails/railtie.rb` with

```
require 'frontrockets-rails'
require 'rails'

module FrontrocketsRails
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    railtie_name :frontrockets

    rake_tasks do
      load 'tasks/frontrockets.rake'
    end
  end  
end
```

and

`lib/frontrockets-rails.rb` with

```
module FrontrocketsRails
  require 'frontrockets-rails/railtie' if defined?(Rails)
end
```

and of course `lib/tasks/frontrockets.rake`

```
namespace :frontrockets do
  desc 'Create .bowerrc file'
  task :create_bowerrc do
    touch '.bowerrc'
  end

  task :install => [:create_bowerrc] do
  end
end
```

But when I install this gem in my Rails app I still can't execute this rake tasks, there are no them in the `rake -T` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just restarted spring and new rake tasks appeared in my `rake -T` list. :)